# How can I change font size in the empty frame editor screen on IntelliJ? Image in Attachment

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

In fact, I would like to customize my IDE IntelliJ, so i changed the texts font type and sizes in the editor and the appearance but i observed that when i have an opened project and i close all the documents there is some gray screen that show up and there, there are some texts indicating shortcuts to navigate in IntelliJ, my question is how can i change the properties of these texts.

Below an image showing the texts I'm talking about.

[image: IntelliJ empty frame]

Comment: changing font size in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance** should work - at least it works for me:)

Comment: @lena , thank you for your response, but I already tried your suggestion but it changes the environment font and size but not those lines!

Comment: Increasing the font size does work for me. But it seems that they can't be made smaller